# MITM of the SSH connection?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, ssh

We connect to the servers via the "FOOBAR" machine.

`desktop` -> FOOBAR(`bar.com`) -> `server`

FOOBAR can log our SSH connections, what we type, etc.

We log in via the following command:

```
ssh -A -t foouser@bar.com sls -c targetuser@targetserver
```

`sls` is "Secure Logging Service"

On the target server side, we can see that **our public key is used** for logging in to the target server.

Our private key is private, only on `desktop`.

`ssh` doesn't display any warning.

**Question**: How is this possible? Isn't it violating SSH end-to-end encryption?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Information Security! You are using ssh agent forwarding.Why do you believe this is violating SSH?

Comment: "FOOBAR can log our SSH connections, what we type, etc. " -> ssh agent allows that the FOOBAR can sniff in the connection? isn't it encrypted end-to-end

Comment: I'm interested in the `sls` part of your command. I'm not familiar with it. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I'm taking a guess at two commands squeezed in one line and edit accordingly. OP mentioned "command**s**" and `ssh` wouldn't make sense with such value for the `-c` either.

Comment: It is in ONE LINE! Don't put the "sls" part in to a second one!! fixed the "commands" part too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute:

```
ssh -A -t foouser@bar.com
```

you are establishing a session between `desktop` and `bar.com`. From now on, everything you type within this session is interpreted by and executed on `bar.com`.

Then you establish a session from `bar.com` to `server` (`sls` is not a standard command, but I assume it is a wrapper for another SSH connection).

You have a second session encrypted between `bar.com` and `server`. This session is authenticated with your private key which is stored on the `desktop` machine.

In the first command you have `-A` argument which enables [agent forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#fwd). This mechanism allows encrypting the session between `bar.com` and the server, using the `desktop` machine (and the private key stored there) for authentication.

It does not mean the second connection is encrypted end-to-end between `desktop` and `server`, it just means `desktop` authorised a session between `bar.com` and `server`.

---

The situation cannot be likened to an attack, because you deliberately choose to use the feature for your own convenience and security (your private key does not leave your machine, you don't store another key with access to `server` on `bar.com`, you don't have to type the password).

The functionality you were seemingly expecting is called [tunneling or port forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) (although must be configured separately). With this you establish two SSH sessions from `desktop` first to `bar.com` then another one to a different port of `bar.com` which would be "bound" to port 22 of `server`. In this scenario `bar.com` would not have the ability to see "inside" the SSH session between `desktop` and `server`.